# react native - Conditionally add node module (react-native-firebase) only in one flavor

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, react-native-firebase, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to separate HMS from GMS based react native application.
So far I've created two flavors (named `huawei` and `google`) which give me the opportunity to apply the respective plugins like so

```
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Huawei")) {
    apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
} else {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
}
```

Everything seems to be conditionable in `build.gradle`. But, when I add `react-native-firebase` and run the Huawei variant, it leads me to the following error:

> No Firebase app '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp(), js engine: hermes

that, according to [this issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2701), can be prevented adding `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of `build.gradle`, but that's what I'm trying to avoid.

So, my question is simple: how can I conditionally add the Android Firebase SDK only to a flavor and do not use it at all in the other? Or.. am I completely wrong in the approach?

Comment: If you're using flavors then both flavor has it's own `google-play-services.json` file and you will need to add in their respective folder

Comment: My goal is to avoid gms usage when I add hms

Comment: OK I got you. You want to disable gms because Huawei doesn't have `google-play-services` support.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point, sorry for not being clear enough

Comment: I'm not sure about React Native specifically, but separating HMS and GMS conditionally on native Android is usually done in the code itself instead of the build.gradle. Are you trying to reduce the size of your package? What is the goal here?

Comment: @Zinna I can include all the necessary to both platforms and handle it js side, but, as you noted, I was trying to reduce package size and avoid any possibile future compatibility problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that handling this on the JS side is the only option here, as the official React Native Firebase documentation states that Google Play Services must be installed in order to function properly.
[https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/faqs#:\~:text=The%20firebase%20SDK%20requires%20a,in%20order%20to%20function%20properly.&text=code%202%20%2D%20Google%20Play%20Services,the%20Play%20Services%20SDK%20installed](https://v5.rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.1.x/faqs#:%5C%7E:text=The%20firebase%20SDK%20requires%20a,in%20order%20to%20function%20properly.&text=code%202%20%2D%20Google%20Play%20Services,the%20Play%20Services%20SDK%20installed).